# Iteración de filas en Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, bucles, dataframe, data

Estoy realizando mis primeros pasos en python y actualmente estoy trabajando con un proyecto en pandas.

La idea del código es realizar una poryección de ventas del mes siguiente en función de las ventas del mes anterior más la media de las variaciones (mes 2 - mes 1). Hasta ahí todo OK, he realizado el cálculo de las diferencias mes a mes y he sacado la media

```
dfv= df
dfv['Variación']= df['CajasDía/Clienta'].diff()
dfv.head()
```

Lo que me devuelve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He calculado la media de la veriación

```
mean= dfv['Variación'].mean()
```

Y lo que quiero realizar es tomando el valor del último mes con datos (mes 15), calcular los valores de los próximos meses:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El valor del mes 16 es el valor del mes 15 + la media, el del 17 el valor del 16 + la media y así sucesivamente.

Ahora he conseguido calcular esto de la siguiente forma

```
proyecciones.iloc[0,1]= mes15 + mean
proyecciones.iloc[1,1]= proyecciones.iloc[0,1] + mean
proyecciones.iloc[2,1]=proyecciones.iloc[1,1] + mean
proyecciones.iloc[3,1]=proyecciones.iloc[2,1] + mean
proyecciones.iloc[4,1]=proyecciones.iloc[3,1] + mean
proyecciones.iloc[5,1]=proyecciones.iloc[4,1] + mean
proyecciones.iloc[6,1]=proyecciones.iloc[5,1] + mean
proyecciones
```

Que me da como resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, los valores son correctos y es lo que esperaba. Pero hay alguna forma de "resumir" el calculo de las proyecciones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar un ciclo `for` para recorrer las columnas e ir accediendo a los valores con `iloc` como ya lo venías haciendo.

```py
for i in range(len(proyecciones)):
    proyecciones.iloc[i,1] = proyecciones.iloc[i-1,1]+mean
```

Comment: Gracias Christian, he con tu comentario he podido solcionar y mejorar el código.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes aprovechar la notación tipo "slice" para actualizar un conjunto de celdas:

```
proyecciones.iloc[1:6, 0:1] = proyecciones.iloc[0:5, 0:1].values + mean
```

Comment: ¿no sería [1:6] en el lado izquierdo y [0:5] en el derecho? Eso es lo que me pareció entender... Junto con `proyecciones.iloc[0,1] = mes15`

Comment: @abulafia, gracias

Comment: Gracias Patricio, he con tu comentario he podido solcionar y mejorar el código.